# Background job with data from background to foreground in Android

Tags: android, android-service

I have an application that needs to track my location, read a sensor while doing this and update a Activity with information (i.e. my current speed). The Activity also has a "stop" button, that allows the user to cancel the background job. The data collection should continue if the user navigates away and notification should allow the user to get back to the view showing the information.

So far I have:

- a Service

  - that has a `private static MyService instance` field and a getter for it
  - it sets `instance = this` in `onStartCommand(...)`
  - it also has a getter for the current data (wrapped in an object)
  - it provides a `goForeground()` method that calls `startForeground(...)` and shows a notification (`goBackground()` does the inverse)
- an Activity

  - that calls `MyService.getInstance()` in `onCreate(...)`, if it returns null it creates the service with `startService(someIntent)`
  - an `updateViews()` method that pulls the data from the Service and uses a Handler to schedule calls to itself to update the Views every 500ms

This works. 
However I'm pretty sure that this is not the recommended way to do this. It's ugly as hell and all calls to the return value of `getInstance()`are wrapped in a not null check. Additionally all the work is happening in the UI thread (which will certainly cause problems when I add more calculations to the Service).  Also, I would like to get rid of the Activity polling the Service for data.

**What is the *recommended* way to do this?**

The Android documentation is not very clear at this point and everything I found with Google was either outdated or solved different problems. Please keep in mind:

- my background job is essentially endless and will not be "finished" at some point in time. Only the user can decide this (this rules out an AsyncTask, or not?)
- I need to pass some non primitive date from the background to the foreground
- I need to control the background from the Activity
- the Activity should be able to "reconnect" to the background if it is closed and reopened

Answer (score 0):

As you said pulling the data from the service is not the best practice, fortunately there is such thing called a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), this class wake up when an intent sent and the receiver is configured to receive it (in the manifest).

This allows your service sending the data when ever its ready, or the other way, your activity can send a request for new data.

note that an intent can hold data, thus you don't need to hold any static instances to services, just pass you data to an intent